# Undefined Offset error when read a file into table

Tags: php, offset

I've got Undefined Offset error, but I don't know what's wrong.

Here's the code

```
<?php

        $documentRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $fileName = "$documentRoot/Tutorials/PHP/Assignments/Assignment 3/data/quote.txt";
        $filePointer = fopen($fileName, 'r');

        $lineCounter = 0;
        $display = "";

        while(true)
        {

            $line = fgets($filePointer);
            list($firstName, $lastName, $contactMethod, $phoneMail, $resideCity, $comments) = explode("|", $line);

            if (!isset($comments))
            {
                $comments = "";
            }

            $lineCounter++;

            if(feof($filePointer))
            {
                break;
            }

            if($lineCounter % 2 == 0)
            {
                $style = "style = 'background-color:white';";
            }
            else
            {
                $style = "style = 'background-color:lightgray';";
            }

            //Write to table

            print"<tr $style>";
            print"<td>$firstName</td>";
            print"<td>$lastName</td>";
            print"<td>$contactMethod</td>";
            print"<td>$phoneMail</td>";
            print"<td>$resideCity</td>";
            print"<td>$comments</td>";
            print"</tr>";
        }

            fclose($filePointer);




        ?>
```

I added:

```
            if (!isset($comments))
            {
                $comments = "";
            }
```

Because I assume the offset error appears because I didn't type in anything in comments. However, I still get this error.

Please help.

Here's the error message:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /Users/Lio/Documents/Eligio's/Tutorials/PHP/Assignments/Assignment 3/quotes.php on line 32
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /Users/Lio/Documents/Eligio's/Tutorials/PHP/Assignments/Assignment 3/quotes.php on line 32
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /Users/Lio/Documents/Eligio's/Tutorials/PHP/Assignments/Assignment 3/quotes.php on line 32
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /Users/Lio/Documents/Eligio's/Tutorials/PHP/Assignments/Assignment 3/quotes.php on line 32
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Users/Lio/Documents/Eligio's/Tutorials/PHP/Assignments/Assignment 3/quotes.php on line 32

Comment: please post the error message itself, with the line at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is before your isset... so when you do explode and pass results to list... that expects 6 parametes only receive 5 or less and you get the error.

I suggest the following replacement:

```
$line = fgets($filePointer);
$data=explode("|", $line);
while(count($data)<6) $data[]="";
list($firstName, $lastName, $contactMethod, $phoneMail, 
$resideCity, $comments) = $data;
```

That will add enough data for list to set vars.

and should work!

Happy coding!

Comment: I checked again... I deleted all the data that's already in the txt, and went through the form (this time with comment). I still got the same error...

Comment: Have you put `while(count($data)<6) $data[]="";` and make the changes proposed? Could you please put a `var_dump($line);` and show us the result? Thank you.